# Evaluating the limit of a complex function

Tags: complex-analysis

> $$f(z) = \begin{cases} \displaystyle{\frac{\bar z^2+4}{z^2+4}|z+2i|^2},&z\neq\pm 2i\\
> 0,&z = \pm 2i\end{cases}$$
>   1. Evaluate $\displaystyle\lim_{z\to 2i} f(z)$ if it exists.
>   2. Evaluate $\displaystyle\lim_{z\to -2i} f(z)$ if it exists.

[Source.](http://s28.postimg.org/7skoask0d/image.jpg)

I have homework tomorrow and solved this problem and found out that these are the answers:

1. 16
2. 0

Could you please verify that I got the correct answers or help me if these answers are wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you know how to use [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/)? This may come in handy.

Comment: For instance, [this](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Limit%5B((Conjugate%5Bz%5D%5E2+%2B+4)%2F(z%5E2+%2B+4))+Abs%5Bz+%2B+2+I%5D%5E2,+z+-%3E+2+I%5D) and [this](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Limit%5B((Conjugate%5Bz%5D%5E2+%2B+4)%2F(z%5E2+%2B+4))+Abs%5Bz+%2B+2+I%5D%5E2,+z+-%3E+-2+I%5D). Note that this will not (and we cannot either, as you did not give any detail on your derivation) tell you if the *way* you arrived to these results is correct.

Comment: Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\frac{\overline z^2+4}{z^2+4}\,|z+2i|^2=\frac{(\overline z-2i)(\overline z+2i)}{(z+2i)(z-2i)}(\overline z-2i)(z+2i)=\frac{(\overline z-2i)^2(\overline z+2i)}{z-2i}\xrightarrow[z\to+-2i]{}?$$

You can now check which limit ($\;z\to2i\;\;or\;\;z\to-2i\;$) exists and which one doesn't.

Comment: They both exist.

Comment: Thank you @ClementC. About $\;z\to-2i\;$ it clearly exists, but I'm not sure about the other one. Maybe later I'll check....oh, of course it does: $$\frac{\overline z+2i}{z-2i}=\frac{\overline{z-2i}}{z-2i}=1$$ and together with $\;(\overline z-2i)^2\to 16\;$ we're done.

Comment: Observe that if $z\to 2i$, then $\bar{z} \to -2i$.  Write $z = 2i + h$ with $h\to$, and you get $$
\frac{(-4i+\bar{h})^2(\bar{h})}{h}
$$
so it boils down to the behavior of $\frac{\bar{h}}{h}$. I'm not entirely sure it does converge any more, but at least it's not as simple as just "looking at it."

Comment: @ClementC. Check what I added to my last comment.

Comment: Yes... I'm rusty, but what does it equal 1?

Comment: @ClementC. Because $\;\overline 1=1\;$ .

Comment: For instance, if "my" $h$ is written $h=ae^{i\theta}$ with $a\to 0$, then $\frac{\bar{h}}{h} = e^{-2i\theta}$. (The conjugate is on the numerator, not the whole fraction.) That quantity depends on $\theta$, which can be aribtrary (not even necessary a constant: take $h_n = \frac{1}{n}\cdot e^{i(-1)^n \pi}$).

Comment: @ClementC. I don't understand: $\;\overline z+2i=\overline{z-2i}\;$ and therefore the fraction in my above comment is zero.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35536/discussion-between-clement-c-and-joanpemo).

Comment: Take $z_n = 2i + \frac{1}{n}$. Then the quantity is $$(-4i+1/n)^2\frac{1/n}{1/n} \xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{} 16.$$ Take $z_n = 2i + \frac{i}{n}$.  Then the quantity is $$(-4i-i/n)^2\frac{-i/n}{i/n} \xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{} -16.$$

Comment: @ClementC. But then you're saying the limit doesn't exist, as you said before, because there are two different sequences that render different limits...I haven't checked your math, by the way.

Comment: Yes, I'm saying that my first gut reaction (also influenced by Wolfram Alpha's result and just eyeballing the thing) was wrong. The limit does not exist when $z\to 2i$. (But not because it blows up to infinity: the function stays bounded, just does not converge.)

Comment: I'd like you to show me what's wrong with my proof, in my above comment, that it does exist.

Comment: You show (writing $\Delta = z-2i$) that you get $$(\bar{z} - 2i)^2\cdot \frac{\bar{\Delta}}{\Delta}.$$ Now, $(\bar{z} - 2i)^2\to 16$, so this term is fine. But we do **not** have necessarily $\frac{\bar{\Delta}}{\Delta} = 1$. Since $\Delta$ is a complex number and can be written $\Delta = \rho e^{i\theta}$, we have $\frac{\bar{\Delta}}{\Delta} = \frac{\rho e^{-i\theta}}{\rho e^{i\theta}}= e^{-i2\theta}$. (I guess the confusion is that we have $\bar{\Delta}/\Delta$, **not** $\overline{\Delta/\Delta} = \overline{1}=1$.)

Comment: Oh, I see...yes, I fell in that confussion. Thanks a lot, @Clement. I shall edit my answer now.

Comment: Well, I was wrong in the very first place :)

Comment: @ClementC. If was a fortunate mistake I did. Not only I got to do some really beautiful mathematics with your help but I also got to meet you :)

Comment: Thank you but I don't see why |z+2i|^2 is equal to what you had put there. And after I substitute z with -2i and check the limit, I am getting 0/-4i which is the same as 0/4 ----> infinity.

Comment: The way I got 16 for z--->2i and 0 for z----->-2i is by using limit properties such as: lim (a . b) = lim a . lim b 
etc

Comment: @Josh Did you follow the above interchange of comments between Clement and me? In it Clement shows why the limit when $\;z\to 2i\;$ doesn't exist and explains what my mistake in other comments was. My answer is fine but doesn't explain all this. The limit when $\;z\to-2i\;$ does exist and equals zero.